# The example of the official manual of Zend Framework 2 does not work apparently

Tags: php, zend-framework

The example program of the Zend Framework 2 Manual, dated March 31 2015, is not working. Here is the code of the elementary part, which is a literal copy.

I would like to know if anyone has used it, and if so, if it worked, and as it has.

application.config.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * If you need an environment-specific system or application configuration,
 * there is an example in the documentation
 * @see http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-system-configuration
 * @see http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-application-configuration
 */
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',
    ),

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ),

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        //'config_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        //'config_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        //'module_map_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        //'module_map_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        //'cache_dir' => $stringPath,

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ),

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    //'service_listener_options' => array(
    //     array(
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ),
    // ),

   // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
   // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
   // 'service_manager' => array(),
);
```

Module.php:

```
<?php

namespace Album;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface {

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

}
```

module.config.php:

```
<?php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),


    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '’controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

AlbumController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function addAction() {

    }

    public function editAction() {

    }

    public function deleteAction() {

    }

}
```

Then create the file and put in index.phtml a normal text.

To load into the browser:

http://localhost/(name of project)/public/album

Appear this error:

> Controller:
>       not-found(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: not-found)

Does anyone know what could happen?

Comment: What is the name of your project?

Comment: "Name of project" is the name of an installed copy of the Zend Skeleton Application. It is installed in a XAMPP, and the way of indexing it in the url is like that. When you download is called ZendSkeletonApplication-master.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg, I made a clumsy mistake. Reference to the controller was erroneous

module.config.php

```
'’controller' =>
```

really is

```
'controller' =>
```